# How can I keep Bootstrap carousel inside a container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be having difficulties with a bootstrap carousel it seems to "Break" outside of the container / row. I'm not 100% sure of what kind of information I may need to provide (First time posting here for help) But here is a screenshot followed by the code (Just a typical bootstrap carousel resized)

#### Screenshot of error

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
.project01-carousel {
 width:640px;
 height:360px;
 }

  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <section class="project01-carousel halfheight">
   <section class="project-carousel-wrap halfheight">

<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="project-carousel owl-carousel owl-nav-sticky-wide">

  <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-01 halfheight 
  text-center">
  <img src="admin/uploaded_image/terrain_renders/<?php echo $row['render1']; 
   ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-02 halfheight 
  text-center">
  <img src="admin/uploaded_image/terrain_renders/<?php echo $row['render2']; 
   ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-03 halfheight 
  text-center">
  <img src="admin/uploaded_image/terrain_renders/<?php echo $row['render3']; 
   ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-04 halfheight 
   text-center">
  <img src="admin/uploaded_image/terrain_renders/<?php echo $row['render4']; 
   ?>">
  </div>
  </div>

  </section>
  </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thinking about this, and could you post a live url where this issue is occurring? Would be even better, cheers! (Actually your static width for the container is probably the culprit).

Comment: try removing width

Comment: Here is the live url http://149.56.129.67/test/terrain.php?id=22 and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have a static width for your content, and I notice you are using Owl Carousel in Bootstrap, so make sure you aren't duplicating any classes there/have [Bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) styles and js turned off so there's no conflicts.

Please note, I only used !important to overcome an img style that was overriding my 100% width call for it. You shouldn't have to use the !important tag in your code.

```css
.project01-carousel {
 /*width:640px;*/
 width: 100%;
max-width: none;
 height:auto;
 border: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 img {
 width: 100% !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <section class="project01-carousel halfheight">
    <section class="project-carousel-wrap halfheight">
      <!-- Carousel -->
      <div class="project-carousel owl-carousel owl-nav-sticky-wide">
        <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-01 halfheight
          text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>
        <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-02 halfheight
          text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>
        <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-03 halfheight
          text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>
        <div class="project-carousel-item project-01-carousel-item-04 halfheight
          text-center">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you should wrap your

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
```

In a row and wrap the row in a container like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
```

And also you should remove  the width for

```
roject01-carousel
```